# Check if an object is non-basetype?

Tags: c#

I want to be able to see if an object is of a base type (char, int, var, string (is this a base type in C#?)). The reason for this is because I want to create a parser, which gets the fields of the object and if it comes across an object it cannot get a value out of (if it was another object inside), it will recursively get the fields out of there too. So for instance:

```
    for (int x = 0; x < elements.Length; x++)
    {
        FieldInfo currenField = fields[x];

        if (currenField is object) //This doesn't work because its of type "FieldInfo"
        {
            //pass in the current object into the function
        }
        else
        {
            elements[x] = new XElement(currenField.Name, currenField.GetValue(obj).ToString());
        }
```

unfortunately I cannot seem to find anything online this will allow you to easily figure out if its a base type. The following is not possible either:

```
      currenField.GetType is typeof(object)
```

TLDR; I cannot determine if something is a base type or not, nor can I compare types to produce the same effect

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In order for us to answer your question, you first need to explain what you mean by "basic type". It's not a standard term.

Comment: Right, for some reason I put that down and then changed it. Its base type you are correct.

Comment: probably referring to IsPrimitive

Comment: It sounds like you need to look into serialization, since you want to write out an XML document that represents a complex type so that it can be re-created later.

Comment: Yes, this is a custom serializer.

Comment: @SergueiFedorov There are *lots* of articles on the subject.  I'm sure you'd be able to find other custom implementations to see how they address different types of issues.

Comment: @Servy its great to read literature like that and I usually do. Trying to find my own way by asking questions here and there. Programming is a deep field with new things to learn all the time and I find that sometimes learning by own way teaches me the most :) We are after all problem solvers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to as "basic types" are actually considered Primitive Types. You can determine if a type is a Primitive Type by using the [`IsPrimitive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive.aspx) property:

```
var type = currenField.GetType();
if(type.IsPrimitive)
    // Primitive type
else
    // Other type
```

Comment: It seems the OP is trying to serialize his data; in that case this isn't really relevant.

Comment: +1 That's most likely what the OP was after. However, it should be noted that there may be a few types that could be parsed, but not covered by the `IsPrimitive` condition (for example `DateTime`).

Comment: @Servy - Unless, of course, the OP wants to write his own serialization code (as a practice exercise, etc.)

Comment: Hmmm, this is interesting. It seems to fail on Strings and not count them as primitives. Then again its not a base type to begin with (or the fancy "primitives" that C# calls them). Looks like I'm going to have to make some exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `IsPrimitive` is enough, but if you need more information, I'd recommend [Type.GetTypeCode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettypecode.aspx).

```
var typeCode = Type.GetTypeCode(currenField.GetType());

switch (typeCode)
{
    case TypeCode.Boolean:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Byte:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Char:
        break;
    case TypeCode.DBNull:
        break;
    case TypeCode.DateTime:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Decimal:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Double:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Empty:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int16:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int32:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Int64:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Object:
        break;
    case TypeCode.SByte:
        break;
    case TypeCode.Single:
        break;
    case TypeCode.String:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt16:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt32:
        break;
    case TypeCode.UInt64:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```